# List of columns for orderBy in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of variables that contains column names. I am trying to use that to call orderBy on a dataframe.

```
val l = List("COL1", "COL2")
df.orderBy(l.mkString(","))
```

But `mkstring` combines the column names to be one string, leading to this error  -

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`COL1,COL2`' given input columns: [COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4];
```

How can I convert this list of strings into different strings so it looks for "COL1", "COL2" instead of "COL1,COL2"?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing single `String` argument is telling Spark to sort data frame using one column with given name. There is a method that accepts multiple column names and you can use it that way:

```
val l = List("COL1", "COL2")
df.orderBy(l.head, l.tail: _*)
```

---

If you care about the order use `Column` version of `orderBy` instead

```
val l = List($"COL1", $"COL2".desc)
df.orderBy(l: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks. This what I wanted. Is there a way to specify desc in here?

Answer (score 2):

You can call orderBy for a specific column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.orderBy(asc("COL1")) // df.orderBy(asc(l.headOption.getOrElse("COL1")))
// OR
df.orderBy(desc("COL1"))
```

If you want sort by multiple columns you can write something like this:

```
val l = List($"COL1", $"COL2".desc)
df.sort(l: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, started with head and tail and eventually came down to using what you have here at the end...

Comment: @NITS Nice! Glad if you are satisfied